# How can I retrieve a picture from my database in PHP?

Tags: php

I've stored an image file on my local drive and the path to that image in my database.  How can I retrieve the image for displaying it in PHP?

Comment: Just like any other data. What's the particular problem? What have you tried already?

Comment: plz tell me how can i get picture which i stoted?

Comment: i've just stored picture in folder through server and their infomation like name, pic_type etc. stored in database. now i want to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Select the data from the DB into variables ($path and $image_name).
echo it (in your view file):

```
echo "<img src='{$path}/{$image_name}' />";
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to write a script to serve the image up on demand, you'll want to take a look at the `readfile()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

You should store the content-type that was sent when the file was originally uploaded too. Keep this with the other information you've saved about the image in the database.

Comment: No need to send file to Output buffer...

Comment: As I said, if you're trying to serve the file ("displaying it in PHP"), use readfile() to send it to the output buffer. We don't know that the local path is publicly accessible.